# Regex Razor Pages Comma and Dot

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, regex, validation

How to allow the user to type commas and dot in a decimal input with razor pages, asp.net core 2.2?
The data is sent by my Database with commas in my edit page, my when I try to save again an error is display: The field VALOR must be a number.

I tried the follow code:

```
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0 - 9]{1, 2})?$", ErrorMessage = "Use apenas caracteres numéricos")]
    [Column("VALOR_UNITARIO", TypeName = "decimal(7,2)")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O campo VALOR UNITÁRIO é obrigatório")]
    [DisplayName("VALOR UNITÁRIO")]
    public decimal VALOR_UNITARIO { get; set; }
```

But the error keeps showing.
Any suggest?

Comment: Try it without the spaces in the pattern `^[0-9]{1,2}([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$`

Comment: There are no spaces I guess, it is a common corruption taking place when pasting from VS

Comment: I tried without the spaces, but it still doesn't work.. I'm guessing there is some sort of error in razor pages that doesn't let me save a decimal number with comma instead of dot. It's a money field I needed to be able to type 2,50 instead 2.50 because when i save this in my database the value is converted to 250.0 and not 2.5. Local format money is ruff =(

Comment: Yes, it is because a regex only works on strings. Use `public string VALOR_UNITARIO`